# In Jenkins/Groovy, why is the redirection in echo > file not printed in the console output?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my Groovy Jenkins pipeline, I have the following:

```
sh(script: """#!/bin/bash
    set -ex
    echo 'sometext' > test1.txt
    """)
```

But in the Jenkins logs, it looks like this:

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
11:43:28  + echo sometext
```

That is, it seems to ignore the ">" operator completely. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that's how `-x` prints the commands into output

try

```
set -ev
```

instead of

```
set -ex
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

> `-v`
> Print shell input lines as they are read.

Comment: Why does it work as desired then with `set -ex` in the `sh` steps in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68824154/1744774)?

Comment: If I understand correctly it's required to see `echo 'sometext' > test1.txt` but `set -ex` outputs to stdout only `echo 'sometext'`

Comment: Ah, now I got it. It's not that the file is not created. It's that the redirection isn't displayed in the build's console output. The question is misleading then, isn't it?

Comment: Hello, yes sorry - I misunderstood the meaning of -x. Add that to my confusion with Jenkins/Groovy and that's how this question was created (I genuinely thought it was a Jenkins escaping idiosyncrasy). I am not sure how to rewrite the question without completely changing it...

Answer (score 1):

##### Pipeline declaration

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('echo to file (short)') {
            steps {
                sh """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    set -ex
                    echo 'sometext' > test1.txt
                    ls -al
                    cat test1.txt
                   """
            }
        }
        stage('echo to file (less short)') {
            steps {
                sh script: """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    set -ex
                    echo 'sometext' > test1.txt
                    ls -al
                    cat test1.txt
                    """
            }
        }    
        stage('echo to file (lesser short)') {
            steps {
                sh( script: """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    set -ex
                    echo 'sometext' > test1.txt
                    ls -al
                    cat test1.txt
                    """)
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

##### Console Output

```bash
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (echo to file (short))
[Pipeline] sh
+ set -ex
+ echo sometext
+ ls -al
total 13
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins Administratoren     0 Aug 17 21:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 jenkins Administratoren 12288 Aug 17 21:01 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins Administratoren     9 Aug 17 21:18 test1.txt
+ cat test1.txt
sometext
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (echo to file (less short))
[Pipeline] sh
+ set -ex
+ echo sometext
+ ls -al
total 13
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins Administratoren     0 Aug 17 21:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 jenkins Administratoren 12288 Aug 17 21:01 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins Administratoren     9 Aug 17 21:18 test1.txt
+ cat test1.txt
sometext
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (echo to file (lesser short))
[Pipeline] sh
+ set -ex
+ echo sometext
+ ls -al
total 13
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins Administratoren     0 Aug 17 21:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 jenkins Administratoren 12288 Aug 17 21:01 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins Administratoren     9 Aug 17 21:18 test1.txt
+ cat test1.txt
sometext
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```